# Getting JSON locally using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have read several questions here stating, that JSON file cannot be loaded locally in Google Chrome due to security policy etc. So I found the solution on http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/.

My javascript now looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var items = [];
    var settingsFile = "corr/settings.json";
    var sidePanel = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('corrPanel').appendTo('body');
    /**
     * Gets JSON file
     * @param  string  jsonFile
     * @return json    file contents
     */
    function getSettings(jsonFile) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', jsonFile, true);
        request.onload = function() {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                jsonRows = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                console.log(jsonRows);
                $.each(jsonRows, function(key, row) {
                    items.push("<input type='text' class='iris' id='" + row.section + "'>");
                });
                console.log(items);
            } else {
                console.log("Error getting JSON file");
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }

    getSettings(settingsFile);
    console.log(items);
});
```

**Console.log returns the output of JSON file without a problem**.

SO, everything works well, but since I am new to JavaScript (and don`t really know how to work with functions and properties there), the **data** property is not set (and returned) so the **result** property is undefined as well.

Could you tell me how to pass the request result outside of the function?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I added pushing results to items array, it is available in local context of the *getSettings* function, but the last console.log has not output.

Comment: `So I found the solution` - no you didn't ... chrome wont read file:/// uri's unless you start it with a specific command line option ... then even jquery works, as jquery just wraps xmlhttprequest anyway

Comment: Na matter what library you use, you can not return response from asynchronous requests. Either use `callbacks` or do the stuff in `success` callback..Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/bt59y2L2/

Comment: @RayonDabre what would be a callback in my case? Since the json is array of objects, could I perhaps iterate them or... could you give me an example on this?

Comment: Basically you do not need callback. Do whatever you need in success handler. May be after `JSON.parse` statement.

Comment: I love that you use jQuery to execute vanilla javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem is that I tried to access the **items** property directly. But the request setting it was called after the page was loaded. So I moved the logic into the success part.

```
if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // execute success code and manage items here ...
}
```